# Can Intervention analysis be used to forecast time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, intervention-analysis

if I have an estimate of the intervention variable from a similarly interrupted time series can it be used to forecast another similar time series after the effect of intervention.

For example lets say FDAs policy change on Hepatitis vaccine has a certain impact on X company's Net Sales. I estimate the intervention variable from here. Now I want to use the estimated variable to find if this policy is introduced for some other drug, regulatory body in another country, how much of shift in the time series of net sales  will happen by the introduction of such policy.

I am trying to use such approach as there is real paucity of data to analyse such regulatory effects.

Comment: Yes, this is called as **analogous** (key word) time series forecasting. You need to lay out causal forces carefully and adapt the analogous data to your current forecasting task. In absence of any historical data such as yours analogous data is some times the **only** modeling  approach  that you an use.  Try key word search analogous time series forecasting, you have quite a bit of  literature out there.